# Handling null value in a dictionary object

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am using a web service to get information. When said info is returned, I convert the data received from jason to a dict.

When Dumping dict object, some of the items arrive like this:

```
▿ (2 elements)

- key: "street1"

- value: <null> #4
```

How would i go about reading this data and knowing that the value is NULL

I have tried the following:

```
let street1:String = dict?["street1"] as! String
```

This fails with: Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x10fbf7918) to 'NSString' (0x10f202c60).

The data could have a String value. So I tried:

```
let street1:Any = dict?["street1"] as Any
```

When I print street1 thus
    street1: Optional()

I get the following
street1: Optional()

So my question is:
How would i go about reading this data and knowing that the value is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if let for this type of nil check.

Try this instead:

```
if let street1 = dict?["street1"] as? String {
   // If this succeeds then you can use street1 in here
   print(street1)
}
```

**Update:**

```
var t_street1 = ""
if let street1 = dict?["street1"] as? String { 
    t_street1 = street1 
}
```

No need for the else `t_street1` is automatically empty since you assign it empty.

Comment: since i need to use the data collected later (sending it back to another service) i ended up doing this: [code]                 var t_street1:String = ""
                
                if let street1 = dict?["street1"] as? String {
                    // If this succeeds then you can use street1 in here
                    t_street1 = street1
                } else {
                t_street1 = ""
                }

Comment: yes it did. is there a more elegant way to do what i tried doing in former comment

Comment: @JohnyDGood, check the updated answer. Consider accepting the answer so that others can benefit from it in the future.